# NSTextField without focus ring causes others to retain ring

Tags: cocoa, focus, first-responder

I have an NSTableView, NSSearchField and an NSTextField. The NSTextField is configured to not have a focus ring. When I tab out of one other other controls, into the NSTextField, the focus ring remains on the previous control, even though the NSTextField is now the first responder.

In the case of the NSTableView, causing a scroll fixes it, but calling setNeedsDisplay does not.

How can I remove the focus ring from the previous control?